# Can I filter error messages from certain sources in the Chrome Dev console?

Tags: console, google-chrome-devtools

In the Chrome DevTools console, I keep getting error messages from certain places that do not actually affect my application's performance. Is there a way to filter out errors from those sources? (e.g., a YouTube iframe with errors, certain Chrome Extensions, etc.)

Comment: See also [filter by selected context](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/images/consolesettings.png) in the console settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, you can.** You are able to filter messages from any file source by right-clicking on the file's name and line (something like `main.js:15`) and selecting `Hide messages from *filename*`. This will block all messages coming from that file (as is probably self-explanatory given what the button says).

**Warning:** This will also block messages using `console.log()` that might harm your debugging process, as well as errors that might come up in the future and be important (which you will now not know about). Use with caution on your own files. It should be harmless with files that aren't yours (again, things like iframes and extensions).

You can reverse the block by going up to the `Filter` dialog box near the top of the console (to the right of the eye icon) and deleting it. (This will also delete all other filters, so you could just remove one if you needed.) You can also more specifically filter messages using `Filter`, but for the purposes of the question (blocking messages from a certain file), it does the job the fastest and the best.

For more information, see: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/reference#filter. This also includes information on the other ways to more specifically filter console messages.

Comment: AWESOME!  this hidden gem just made my debugging a lot less confusing

Answer (score 3):

At the top of your console is a filter box.  Here you can do

- plain text search
- regular expression search such as `/\d+\s\d+/`
- attribute, such as `url:pagead`
- negate any of the above with prefix `-`.
- combine (*AND*) any of the above with space

For example `-url:pagead` will filter out all messages that have `pagead` in the url. There are two other attributes `context:` and `source:`, but I don't know what they do.

For example, `def anon` will show only messages that contain both `def` and `anon` (not necessarily together).

I have not found any way to OR two expressions (UNION).

see [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/reference/)